# how to order a list based on a join model's attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have piece and lineup joined by piece_lineup

piece_lineup is a has many through relationship join and has an attribute 'position'

how would I sort a list of pieces based on their related position attribute in the join model.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
class Piece < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :piece_lineups
  has_many :lineups, :through => :piece_lineups, 
             :order => "piece_lineups.position"
end
```

Now `piece.lineups` is sorted as per your requirement.

Comment: do you mean lineup.pieces? that is what I'm trying to order

Answer (score 0):

I think this may now do:

```
Piece.joins(:piece_lineups).order("piece_lineups.some_attribute DESC")
```

If you just want the order of pieces according to 'attribute', then 'joins' is best.

If you do want this is the model instead, then you only need:

```
class Piece < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :lineups, :order => 'lineups.postion'
end
```

Comment: This introduces a default sorting on the set of piece_lineups that belong to a certain piece. He instead wants to sort the pieces themselves using the piece_lineups' position attribute.

Comment: @cdesrosiers Thanks. Misunderstood the question. Revised my answer.

Comment: @MatthewBerman Updated my answer for the solution to be within the model.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Piece.includes(:piece_lineups).where('some condition').order('piece_lineups.position')
```